# Extract all posts on a user's Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying to make a summary of all the wall posts made on a company's Facebook wall but I'd like to have all the posts in XML-like format. I'm aware of the Graph API but I've never used it before.

The exact specific problem:
**How can I 'extract' all wall posts made on a company's Facebook wall?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following with Graph API.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[company_page_id]/posts?access_token=XXXXXXX
```